# Wusa exit code "0x00240005 vs 0x00000BC2"

Tags: windows-update

I cannot get the difference between 2 exit codes that wusa.exe may return:

> 0x00240005 WU_S_REBOOT_REQUIRED The system must be restarted to complete installation of the update,
>
> 0x00000BC2 Error_Success_Reboot_Required

http://inetexplorer.mvps.org/archive/windows_update_codes.htm
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/938205/windows-update-error-code-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the description of the error codes as available in [Microsoft's own CMTrace tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=50012); particularly referring from Error Lookup (Ctrl + L) in the tool:

> 0x00240005: The system must be restarted to complete installation of
>   the update. 
>   ***Source: Windows Update Agent***
>
> 0x00000BC2: The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be
>   effective until the system is rebooted. ***Source: Windows***

These error codes are from different sources. First one is applicable specifically for Windows Update, whereas the second one can be applicable on any such Windows based operation where the requested operation was successful, but the changes won't be effective until reboot.

I hope this helps. And, I'd suggest you to use this tool for getting more information in this regard.